# firebase rules, create an user PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I get PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied when try to create an user:

```
{
 "rules": {

   ".read": true,
   ".write": "auth != null",

    "users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".validate": "
            newData.child('user').isString() &&
            newData.child('user').val().length > 3
        "
    }
 }

 }
}
```

user is string, has more than 3 letters. But I think it has something to do with the id.

I create an user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and try to insert it on database:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
    username: username,
    email: email
});
```

The userID is the id `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns...

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: The problem most probably comes form the `.validate` part.

Comment: How are your setting the data? I mean are you using cloud functions?

Comment: You're passing a property `username` in your code, but are validating `user` in your rules. Since `user` <> `username` the rules reject the write.

Comment: also `".write": "auth != null",` is working over the users write... any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You problem comes from the `.validate` part: with your rules you need to write a node as follows

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
    user: username,   // <-- see here we have a user sub-node
    email: email
});
```

---

Or you need to change your rules as follows:

```
{
 "rules": {

   ".read": true,
   ".write": "auth != null",

    "users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".validate": "
            newData.child('username').isString() &&
            newData.child('username').val().length > 3
        "
    }
 }

 }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can easily spot this kind of problem by using the "Rules Playground" module in the Firebase console.